# Can subjective and experimental literature be extended?

Tags: sentence-structure, sentence-choice, sentence

> Considering the extended subjective and experimental literature of the
> published studies in valid international datebases and the fact that
> this kind of attitude toward the research in this field includes three
> levels...

The above sentence is the whole sentence, Is it right grammatically and other aspects?

Comment: Does it end with an ellipsis (...) ?

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the text that you quote.  That means title, author, and publication, or as many of those as are available. If the source is long, such as a book, please include a page number or other location also. If the source is online, please include a link also. See [**Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457)

Comment: I speak English perfectly well, but the cited text is impenetrable to me. Quest1000 - Having said that, I assume you're actually just asking whether ***extended*** modifies only ***subjective** [literature]*, or does it also modify ***experimental** [literature]*? Did you write the text yourself? It's only a "fragment" (***not*** a complete sentence), but it looks to be syntactically valid, so far as it goes. (It's *awful* English, though! :)

Comment: I rather suspect that "extended" is being used to mean "extensive" here, that is, the author is saying that there is a lot of such literature. The writing is a bit turgid, however. Please provide the source, both for  context and for proper credit.